# c# storing richtextbox user input into string array elements with defined length

Tags: c#, arrays, string, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox named rtbDisclaimer. It's set to limit user input to 500 characters. I have been trying to figure out a way to take whatever the user types into the rtb, and break it into an array of strings with each string element limited to a certain character length, such as 100 for example, however if the 100th character is in the middle of a word I don't want it to include that word, but rather to put it in the next element so that words are not cut in half. Basically, if a user types in 500 characters, the whole thing would be broken into 5 or 6 string array elements with each element limited to 100 characters maximum without cutting any words in half. I've searched around and haven't been able to find anything that would work, and can't quite figure out how to tackle this problem. Also, the user input can be any length up to 500, so this would need to be flexible to allow for a input ranging anywhere from 0 - 500 characters.

Ex:
**Not this:**

[0]This is the user input typed into the ri

[1]chtextbox as it would appear in the ar

[2]ray elements

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**This:**

[0]This is the user input typed into the

[1]richtextbox as it would appear in the

[2]array elements

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
var longText = "this morning, bla blabla";

var words = longText.split(' '); // split on space

var sentences = new List<string>();
var currentSentence = string.Empty();

foreach(var word in words){
    if((sentence.Length + word.Length + 1) < 100){  
            currentSentence += word + " ";
        }
    else{
        sentences.Add(currentSentence);
        currentSentence = word;
    }
}
```

Comment: The biggest problem, is that it's a richtextbox, so getting it into a string is enough of a challenge, then trying to do everything else with the array makes it that much more of a pain.

Comment: var text = myRichTextBox.Text; What is hard about that?